# SwiftUI @State enum remains nil even after assigning a value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Xcode 12 + iOS 14 beta 8

I have a SwiftUI view that can present three different sheets based on the state of the app. Instead of having three separate .sheet modifiers and three different `@State` properties to handles these sheets, I thought using an enum to determine which sheet to present would be an elegant solution...but it doesn't work.

Here's the enum:

```swift
enum SheetType: Int, Identifiable {
    case welcome
    case notification
    case assignment

    var id: Int { rawValue }
}
```

`SheetType` has to conform to Identifiable because of the `.sheet(item:content:)` modifier in the view:

```swift
struct MainTabView: View {
    @State var sheetType: SheetType?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
        .onAppear(perform: checkForSheet)
        .sheet(item: $sheetType) { _ in
            sheetView
        }
    }
}
```

When `MainTabView` appears, `checkForSheet` looks for conditions that would warrant the presentation of a specific sheet, and if any match, sets the `sheetType` property like so: `sheetType = .welcome`. This should then call `sheetView` which returns the matching sheet.

The problem is that no matter where in the code I update the value of `sheetType`, it remains nil. I can see the value change for a split second in the debugger but then it switches back to nil before a sheet can be presented. I'm at a total loss. Is there something obvious I'm missing or is this just another bug?

---

***EDIT 1:***

Thanks to *Asperi* 's code I was able to get the sheet to present, but the problem is that the `sheetView` property that returns the proper sheet isn't working either. I've changed it to a function instead and tweaked the `.sheet` modifier:

```
.sheet(item: $sheetType) { type in
    createSheetView(of: type)
}
```

Here's the code for `createSheetView(of:)`. I've confirmed in the debugger that the value of `sheetType` is `.welcome`, but switch statement still returns the default value, which is a useless `EmptyView`.

```
func createSheetView(of type: SheetType) -> some View {
    switch sheetType {
    case .welcome: return AnyView(WelcomeSplashView())
    case .notification: return AnyView(NotificationPermissionView(notificationAccessWasGranted: .constant(false)))
    default:
        return AnyView(EmptyView())
    }
}
```

---

***EDIT 2:***

I'm a moron. I forgot to change the switch statement from `switch sheetType` (which is the `@State` property of the view) to the new `switch type` (which takes the parameter of the function). It works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some replicated code that works with Xcode 12b5

[image: demo]

```
enum SheetType: Int, Identifiable {
    case welcome
    case notification
    case assignment

    var id: Int { rawValue }
}

struct MainTabView: View {
    @State var sheetType: SheetType?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
        .onAppear(perform: checkForSheet)
        .sheet(item: $sheetType) { _ in
            Text("sheetView")
        }
    }

    func checkForSheet() {
        sheetType = .welcome   // << make sure to update always in main queue
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm...I played around with this code and it looks like having the conditional view inside sheet is what's causing the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I added some more code to my original post if you have time to take another look. Thanks!